# Learning to conceptualize Data Binding

Tags: angular, dom, data-binding

I am learning Angular, specifically about data binding.

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components shows visual half-way down the page showing a directional data flow between the DOM and a Component.

These lines between the DOM and Component (left, right) are confusing me. What does it mean when {{value}} goes left from Component to the DOM? What does it mean when the arrow points right from DOM to component with (event) = "handler" in between?

I thought data binding meant binding data from the view in .html to the controller in a corresponding .ts and vice versa. Where is the DOM in this, and where does my understanding start to go awry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an example of 2 way data binding and your initial thought about how it works is correct.

The DOM is in the browser, it is what builds the actual representation of the page for the user to view.

When you create a variable in the component, it becomes available to use in the DOM:

```
testString: string = 'here is some text';
```

That can now be accessed in the HTML for the view:

```
<span>{{ testString }}</span>
```

But it also can be used in inputs, radio buttons, selects, etc and when the user enters a value, the variable in the controller assumes that value:

```
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='testString'>
```

Now when the page loads 'here is some text' will appear in the input but any other text the user types replaces that and becomes the value stored in testString. If you added a onChange method to the input that imply console logged this.testString you'd see it always matches the value in the input.

A quote from that section of the docs you linked explains it well:

> In two-way binding, a data property value flows to the input box from the component as with property binding. The user's changes also flow back to the component, resetting the property to the latest value, as with event binding.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Component  -> DOM` doesn't make sense to me in that I imagine `{{value}}` to be interpolating the value from the DOM and outputting it to the component's view.
Why is this understanding incorrect? The component is displaying this value from the DOM, shouldn't the flow be `DOM -> Component` ?

(this is all in reference to the image described in the linked article of the original post)

Comment: It's two way data binding. If you loaded data via an API into the controller then it could show in the view on page load. The user could then edit the data and have it flow back to the component. Basically, a change to the value in one is instantly updated in the other (view and component).

Comment: I am starting to "Get it" when I think of the .html and the .ts files separately from how the DOM is working in the background.

Comment: Yeah, just think of the DOM as the mechanism in the background that takes the information from the component and builds the view. It really just comes down to component and view as the actual parts you interact with.